# Convert .htaccess to Nginx rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

I have a PHP application and I try to install in on a subfolder. I have  the `.htaccess` rule like below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /res/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /res/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I converted it to this in Nginx:

```
location /res {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /res/index.php?q=$uri;
}
```

But it does not work.

Comment: It looks like you might have a typo there? `res` rather than `rest`?

Comment: Oh, this is a mistake, I changed the question. It still doesn't work.

Comment: What does not work? What did you try exactly, what errors did you get? What you expect instead?

Comment: I got error HTTP ERROR 500